# separating lines of printed text when using printf

Tags: java, printf

Working on a project that requires something to be printed as "printf" but the next line then ends up on the same line as the previous one, how would I go about seperating these?

```
System.out.print("Cost per course: ");
double costPerCourse1;
costPerCourse1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.printf("%.2f", costPerCourse1 + /n);

double tuition;
tuition = numberOfClasses1 * costPerCourse1;
System.out.println("Tuition: " + tuition);
```

Comment: What output do you expect ??

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass a new line character into the *argument* String, something that I don't think work. Better is to include `"%n"` within the *format* String passed into printf and that will give you an OS independent new line. For example:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", costPerCourse1);
```

Or you could simply follow your printf with an empty SOP call.

**Edit**
I'm wrong. An argument String can have a valid newline char and it works:

```
public class TestPrintf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String format1 = "Format String 1: %s";
        String arg1 = "\nArgument String 1 that has new line\n";

        System.out.printf(format1, arg1);

        String format2 = "Format String 2 has new line: %n%s%n";
        String arg2 = "Argument String2 without new line";

        System.out.printf(format2, arg2);

    }
}
```

returns:

```
Format String 1: 
Argument String 1 that has new line
Format String 2 has new line: 
Argument String21 without new line
```

Or:

```
System.out.printf("%s: %.4f%s%s", "Value:", Math.PI, "\n", "next String");
```

returns:

```
Value:: 3.1416
next String
```

Comment: NINJA'D! - well, honesly, it *would* work for a `%s` or `%c` - i.e. `System.out.printf("%.2f%c", costPerCourse1, '\n');` - I'm not saying that it's a good solution (it ain't, since `%n` or even plain `\n` in format is obviously better) - but it *would* work.

Comment: @huntervike: I'm wrong, an argument String can have a functioning newline char. Please see edit answer.

Comment: @vaxquis: Thanks for the comment. I think that I was posting my edit at the same time as you your comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [I've pressed Enter the same moment "an edit to the post" appeared on my screen ^_^](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/cardfight/images/6/6b/Ninjad2.png/revision/latest?cb=20140408124405)